# Hibernate mapping a Map<Enum,Double>

Tags: hibernate, jpa, annotations

How can i map this in Hibernate :

```
 Map<Day, Double> dayCounter;
```

where Day is:

```
public enum Day {

    MONDAY,

    TUESDAY,

    WEDNESDAY,

    THURSDAY,

    FRIDAY;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
   @ElementCollection
   //define your collection table using @CollectionTable
   @MapKeyEnumerated(EnumType.STRING)
   @MapKeyColumn(name = "day")
   @Column(name = "count")
   private Map<Day, Double> dayCount;
```